# How to use LIKE OR operator using cakephp & mysql

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakephp & don't know what is the syntax to use **LIKE** & **OR** operator in cakephp with mysql.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks..

Comment: Where in cakePHP? I don't understand. Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Complex find conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions) from the manual:

```
$this->Post->find('first', array (
    "Author.name" => "Bob", 
    "OR" => array (
        "Post.title LIKE" => "%magic%",
        "Post.created >" => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-2 weeks"))
    )
));
```

Comment: Just a side note. I had issues when using only on percent sign, like the above code segment: 
    `"Post.title LIKE" => "%magic%",`
In my code the string $File_Root was known it was the file extension that wasn't. But I had to use bookend percent signs anyway for cakephp 2.7 to use the LIKE keyword. Here is my code segment of the larger find statement.
    `array( 'conditions' => array('file_name LIKE' => "%$File_Root%"))`

Answer (score 5):

you can use:
 for "like"

```
$this->Post->find("all",array('condition'=>array('Author LIKE'=>"ad%")));
```

above query will give You the data from table posts where author name starts with "ad".

for "OR"

```
$this->Post->find("all",array('condition'=>array("OR"=>array('Author LIKE'=>"ad%",'Post LIKE'=>"bo%"))));
```

above query will give You the data from table posts where author name starts with "ad" OR Post starts with "bo".

Comment: Not sure which version of CakePHP suraj is using, but as written, his second query doesn't work in 1.2, since the second `Author LIKE` condition ("bo%") overwrites the first `Author LIKE` condition ("ad%").  Adding a space after the word `LIKE` in the second condition keeps it from overwriting the first.

Answer (score 0):

if you using where function then use this :-

```
->where(['Products.category_id'=>1, 'Products.name LIKE' =>'test%'])
```

thanks