# CakePHP, MongoDB: How to search field from Collection

Tags: mongodb, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to implement functionality that will search the record from mongoDB. I am using [ichikaway](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/) plugin.
I tried the cakephp `like` clause mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022569/how-to-use-like-or-operator-using-cakephp-mysql), but did not worked for me :(.

please let me if there is any approach to achieve this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing search around I have found solution

`$conditions = array('field_name' => new MongoRegex('/'.$value.'/i'));`

where `i` trans to case-insensitive.