# Problem receiving user id in SQL query - Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Friends, I need to do a search for records in a user's view. Only the records registered by him will be displayed. I have this query:

```
      $user = $this->Users
      ->find('all')
      ->contain('Products', function (\Cake\ORM\Query $q) {
          return $q->where(['Products.name LIKE' => '%'.$this->request->getQuery('keyword').'%' ]);
      })
      ->where([ 'Users.id' => 'Products.user_id' ])
      ->toArray();
  
      $this->set('user', $user);
      $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
```

I believe that my problem is in this line, because I do not receive the user id. I tried to go through a parameter, but it didn't work either. I'm getting the error: **Cannot convert value of type `string` to integer**

Using

```
$id = $this->request->getParam('pass');
```

I also get through this:

```
$id = $this->request->getAttribute('params');

debug
_____
    [
    'controller' => 'Users',
    'action' => 'detailUser',
    'pass' => [
        (int) 0 => '17'
    ],
____
```

I can get the user id, but I don't understand how to enter the information in the query.
I appreciate if anyone can analyze.

Comment: `Products.nameLIKE` looks like a typo. The operator should be separate from the column. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022569/how-to-use-like-or-operator-using-cakephp-mysql/3022873 would be useful

Comment: Thank you. It was a typo, but the problem remains. I believe it is in the where clause ...

Comment: Can you please update the code in the question to show the correct code?

Comment: `->where(['Products.user_id' => $id])`

Comment: I did a test by inserting id=17, for example. It works! -> where (['Users.id' => 17]). But when I do -> where (['Users.id' => $ id]) occurs: Cannot convert value of type `array` to integer. I used $id = $this->request->getParam ('pass').  Debug: [ (int) 0 => '17']